# Adblock browsing history security

Tags: privacy, web-browser

A lot of people use adblock.

From a security aspect, ad blocking would involve intercepting and parsing HTML contents and URL's. Hackers attacking adblock servers could gain access to that valuable stream of data.

By activating adblock in our browser, are we effectively allowing adblock servers to see all our browsing history to process them to remove the ads?

Does adblock actively send full URL's to adblock servers, even for pages that had no ads finally ?

Comment: What is an "adblock server"?

Comment: The servers used by the algorithms for filtering ads

Comment: Can you give an example of such a server?

Comment: You mean the IP addresses? I'm not sure I understand your question. However this question makes assumptions on how adblock potentially works which might happen differently in reality so if you have any answers please let me know. It is my question ultimately.

Answer (score 4):

> ... are we effectively allowing adblock servers to see all our browsing history to process them to remove the ads?

The only servers involved when doing ad-blocking in AdBlockPlus, uBlock and several other products are the servers providing the filter rules. These rules are downloaded locally to the client and used there in the ad-blocking browser extension. This means there is no access to some "adblock server" (whatever this is) to block a specific ad or ads from a specific site.

Of course one might create a proxy which includes such ad-filtering and several firewalls also block ads for security reasons. In this case the proxy/firewall has of course knowledge of the site you currently access. And of course an ad-blocking extension also knows which site you access and thus it might in theory send these URL's to some 3rd party.

But considerng on how much tracking and malvertisement ad-blocking removes you are probably more safe and less tracked when using a widely used ad-blocking extension (preferable with open source code so you could verify the behavior) than to keep surfing with ads and tracking enabled.

Comment: I see I had it all wrong then, thank you for the answer.